# Parsing JSON in Java Play

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a simple JSON object I wish to parse in Play, I am currently trying the following but having no luck:

```
    HashMap<String,Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(stringBuilder.toString(), HashMap.class);
```

My JSON Object looks like the following:

```
[{"id":"537b4f2e30047c51863094dd","from":"jacob","to":"duncan","subject":"Welcome to the message system!","message":"Hello World"},{"id":"537bb23930044f26cfd24464","from":"jacob","to":"duncan","subject":"Welcome to the message system!","message":"Hello World"}]
```

Can anybody provide an example on how to parse and iterate over this?

Comment: Would this http://www.javabeat.net/using-jsonslurper-groovy-api-from-java-to-parse-json/ work for you?

Comment: Which Play version exactly do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Play 2 uses Jackson API for JSON, so you should use it

Sample:

```
String jsonString = "[{\"id\":\"537b4f2e30047c51863094dd\",\"from\":\"jacob\",\"to\":\"duncan\",\"subject\":\"Welcome to the message system!\",\"message\":\"Hello World\"},{\"id\":\"537bb23930044f26cfd24464\",\"from\":\"jacob\",\"to\":\"duncan\",\"subject\":\"Welcome to the message system!\",\"message\":\"Hello World\"}]";
JsonNode node = Json.parse(jsonString);
if (node.isArray()) {
    Iterator<JsonNode> elements = node.elements();
    while (elements.hasNext()) {
        JsonNode obj = elements.next();
        debug(
                "Message with ID: " + obj.get("id")
                + " from: " + obj.get("from")
                + " to: " + obj.get("to")
                + " subject: " + obj.get("subject")
                + " message: " + obj.get("message")
        );
    }
}
```

Tip: *It was refactored some time ago, so depending on used Play version check [Codehaus Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) or [FasterXML Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) APIs*

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a list, where each entry is a map key value pairs.
You can use a standard json parser to convert it into an object like this:

```
    String json = "[{\"id\":\"537b4f2e30047c51863094dd\",\"from\":\"jacob\",\"to\":\"duncan\",\"subject\":\"Welcome to the message system!\",\"message\":\"Hello World\"},{\"id\":\"537bb23930044f26cfd24464\",\"from\":\"jacob\",\"to\":\"duncan\",\"subject\":\"Welcome to the message system!\",\"message\":\"Hello World\"}]";
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){}.getType();
    List<Map<String, Object>> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, listType);
```

Then you can iterate over the `List` and each `Map` as normal:

```
    for (Map<String, Object> map : data) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

---

**P.S.**
It looks like all your value data is also in `String` form, so you might want to consider making a `Map<String, String>` instead of `Map<String, Object>` if that's actually the case.